# How to obtain the insider build of Azure Data Studio?

Tags: azure-data-studio

I hear a lot about the insider preview build of Azure Data Studio but could not find any download link on the official Microsoft pages.

How do I receive the insider build of the application?

Comment: Closed so can't answer - but the links to the insiders builds are here : https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio#try-out-the-latest-insiders-build-from-master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can be found on Github

https://github.com/Microsoft/azuredatastudio/releases

As of Oct 2018, they do main releases once a month and dev releases in the middle of the month

Also note that SQL Ops Studio is deprecated.